# Loading all content (images) at once to increase site performance

Tags: jquery, image, web, load

I recently did some website analysis [On My Site](http://nanisolutions.us/wordpress/mitzvah/) to find that 90% of my site's loading time is coming from the 100's of images I have on the site. I have already cropped and compressed all images so that they are around 120kb in size (each).

Is there a way using jQuery perhaps that I could cache each image as the site loads so that each page doesn't take 10 - 12 seconds to load?  If not, does anyone reading this have any better ideas? As of now, when each page loads it first loads the thumbnail images you see on the right hand side, and it will then load the larger images in the center of the screen.

I appreciate any help!

- Evan

Comment: The images are 855px x 570px - do you have any better ideas? They started off as 15 megs.

Comment: Wow, I wound up giving up waiting for your page to load. That's pretty nuts...

Comment: Tell me about it! I am in dire need of some help here!

Comment: Do you think something like jQuery Lazy Load Plugin (http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) might do the trick?

Comment: You're only showing a few thumbnails and an image at the time. Do not load the images that are not shown, load them on user interaction only and use a spinner/loader while it waits. Sure beats waiting a minute for your site to load?

Comment: I love the Lazy load idea - that looks awesome! I'll definitely check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way using jQuery perhaps that I could cache each image as
>   the site loads so that each page doesn't take 10 - 12 seconds to load?

Caching is controlled with HTTP headers (which you should certainly be setting) but regardless of caching the initial load time will be way too high if you are loading hundreds of images at 120KB each.

*Preloading* can be accomplished with a little JavaScript (jQuery or not) but you probably shouldn't be preloading hundreds of images (I would be unhappy if a site silently ate up all my bandwidth in the background).

I suggest either loading the full-size images on demand (e.g. user clicks on a thumbnail) and/or lazy loading images (e.g. only loading them when they are scrolled into view).

Given the layout of your site, I would:

- load the first visible image
- preload the images for each visible thumbnail
- preload a few more images whenever the user hits the "down" arrow.

Couple misc. notes:

- http://gtmetrix.com/ is a great site for performance analysis.
- Your layout is a little confusing on really wide monitors. On my 2500x1600 display, the arrows which control the thumbnails are several hundred pixels away which makes them hard to notice.[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Agreed. I think the idea is to load images upon request. Load as many of those tiny thumbnails as you'd like, but only load the larger images as they're requested.

Comment: Okay, I see. I will figure out how on earth to do this - perhaps the plugin is the way to go?

Comment: @Evan - This is a pretty easy layout. Click on an thumbnail, and load it. Even without lazy loading/preloading it would probably work fine; *with* lazy loading it will be extremely smooth. A plugin will work fine if you aren't familiar with how to code it yourself.

Comment: Alright, I like the plugin idea. I will mark this as correct, but by any chance could I leave a question if I run into one?

Comment: @Evan - sure. If the question is different than the original topic, feel free to open a new question.

Comment: @TimMedora Could you send me a screenshot of what you see on your 2500 monitor?

Comment: @Evan - just added a screenshot.

Comment: @TimMedora Alright, not sure what I can do about that just yet, but I'll figure it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Thought I'd throw this in as an answer because you liked my lazy load comment.

Try using [Lazy Load Plugin for jQuery](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload).

Answer (score 1):

This is reminiscent of the 90s and "hover" images...

You can use [Image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLImageElement) in JavaScript and pre-load them in to the browser cache, if that's what you're after:

```
var i = new Image();
i.src = "/path.to/image.jpg";
```

Or, for a collection:

```
var images = Array();
images[0] = '...1.jpg';
images[1] = '...2.jpg';
images[2] = '...3.jpg';

var img = new Image();
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
  img.src = images[i];
}
```