# Dynamically load a bunch of images all at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, lazy-loading

I am lazy-loading HTML while the user is scrolling down. The HTML contains some basic elements as well as an image which needs to be downloaded from the server. If I try to load too many images all at once, the download time slows down. Also, it is way slower than if I were to deliver all the images in the HTML instead of dynamically loading them.

For now I am trying to sequentially load the images in here http://bredymer.dk/biler.aspx . You initiate download of 5 images, wait for them to load, then initiate download for next 5 images and wait for them to load and keep on going like that. However, that is far from ideal because some images are downloaded quicker than others and while the browser could start fetching new images, it is waiting for all 5 to get downloaded.

So I am wondering is there some best practices of how to deal with dynamically loaded images, especially if there is a whole bunch of them? Or a plugin which speeds up dynamically loaded resources loading?

Comment: could you not use something similar to multithreading? like a web worker/etc? http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/introducing-html-5-web-workers-bringing-multi-threading-to-javascript.html#fbid=96Oy-KoC9LC

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading all content (images) at once to increase site performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273375/loading-all-content-images-at-once-to-increase-site-performance)

Comment: Thanks, I will investigate multithreading. I don't think it's a duplicate because there he is able to show images on demand while here I need to show images on screen immediately. But there are some good answers, I will investigate.

Comment: Could load all images , at document load , into element with `style="display:none"` , then load the images from that element into the displayed document.